# mysql - trying to update previous lines with a subsequent value

Tags: php, mysql, database

first of all a short extract of my database

```
eau      smr     uhrzeit  bon
42203414 gelesen 08:53:25      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:29      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:32      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:35      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:38      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:41      0
42203414 ge1esen 08:53:45      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:48      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:51      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:54      0
42203414 gelesen 08:53:58      0
42203414 gelesen 08:54:01      0
42203414 gelesen 08:54:04      0
       0 bon     08:54:10 254908
```

As you can see the column bon contains '0' in all fields where smr 'gelesen' appears. right now i am trying to update all previous the fields where a '0' stands with the value out of the field '254908'.

So basically I want the table to be like this:

```
eau      smr     uhrzeit  bon
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:25 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:29 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:32 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:35 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:38 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:41 254908
    42203414 ge1esen 08:53:45 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:48 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:51 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:54 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:53:58 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:54:01 254908
    42203414 gelesen 08:54:04 254908
           0 bon     08:54:10 254908
```

Now I want to write a php code that compares the time and updates the bon field with '254908' in case the time is < than the time out of the 'bon' line. throughout the database this pattern continues and i basically just want to update the fields with '0' with the associated numer (in this case 254908)

greetings

Comment: "...updates the bon field with '254908' in case **the time** is < than the time out of the 'bon' line." - which time should be smaller than the time in the bon line?

Comment: `update [tablename] SET bon=254908 WHERE uhrzeit > $time;`